# RESTful tutorial with Java(vogella) - understanding why PathParam invoke method on other resource

Tags: java, rest

I really try to understand why calling url:
 http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.todo/rest/todos/1
cause invocation of `getTodo()` on **TodoResource.java** :

```
//Application integration     
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Todo getTodo() {...}
```

right after:

```
@Path("{todo}")
public TodoResource getTodo(@PathParam("todo") String id) {}
```

on **TodosResource.java** -> this one is obvious.

all sources are here:

[www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html#crud](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html#crud)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your link :

> ```
> // Defines that the next path parameter after todos is
> // treated as a parameter and passed to the TodoResources
> // Allows to type http://localhost:8080/com.vogella.jersey.todo/rest/todos/1
> // 1 will be treaded as parameter todo and passed to TodoResource
> @Path("{todo}")
> public TodoResource getTodo(@PathParam("todo") String id) {
>   return new TodoResource(uriInfo, request, id);
> }
> ```